# ToC won't display a short part title with titlesec/titletoc formatting

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec, parts, titletoc

I'm currently using the titlesec/titletoc combination to (re)define the way part title is displayed, both in ToC and in text.

I'm using the `\chapter[short title]{long\\long title}` command to obtain two distinct results into ToC and text. And it works. However, it does not seem to work for part names, with `\part[short part]{long\\part name}`.

Here is the MWE :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 12pt]{book}

% GENERAL %

\usepackage[notlof, nottoc, notlot]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo} % Font


\usepackage[raggedright, pagestyles, outermarks, toctitles, newparttoc]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{part}[0pt]{\centering\Large\scshape}{}{}{}%

\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\raggedleft\fontsize{45}{60}\selectfont\scshape}
{}
{0em}
{}[]% retirer la bande noire pour la suite


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part[Short part title]{Long part\\title}
\chapter[Short title]{Long\\long title}

\end{document}
```

Which sadly renders ToC part title as `Long part\\title` instead of `Short part title`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `titlesec`'s option `toctitles`.

> `toctitles` (Package option)
>
> `2.6` Changes the behaviour of the optional argument in sectioning titles so that it sets only the running heads and not the TOC entries, which will be based on the full title.

That it applied to Parts only is presumably related to the usage of `\titleformat` only for `\part`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems that I have read the documentation too fast. Now I can't remember why I added this option. Anyway, it does not seem to produce unwanted side effects to remove it.